# Why does electric potential decreases along the direction of electric field?

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, potential, voltage, conventions

I've been reading about Equipotential Surfaces and I came across this statement which I'm not able to understand conceptually. Does it's mathematical proof has something related to $\mathrm d V = -E.\mathrm d r$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A unit positive charge will have a force on it due to the electric field in the direction of the electric field.
In moving in that direction from position $A$ to position $B$ the electric field does work on the positive charge $\displaystyle \int ^B_A E(x)\, dx$ and this is a positive quantity.

By definition the difference in potential in going from position $A$ to position $B$ is given by $V_{\rm B}-V_{\rm A} = -\displaystyle \int ^B_A E(x)\, dx$.
As the integral is positive it means that $V_{\rm B}-V_{\rm A}$ is negative ie $V_{\rm A}>V_{\rm B}$

In effect the unit positive charge is going down a potential slope.

Another relationship which can be used is $E \,\hat x = - \dfrac{dV}{dx} \hat x$.

If $E$ is positive it means that the potential gradient, $\dfrac{dV}{dx}$, the rate of change of potential with position, is negative ie the potential is decreasing with increasing $x$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of electric potential energy

$$dU=-dW_{electric}$$

In general potential energy is defined as
$$dU=-dW_{int,cons}$$

The above equation says that the change in potential energy of a system is defined as the negative of work done by the internal conservative forces of the system

In fact,

$$dV=\frac{-dW_{elect}}{q}$$
If you solve the above equation further by using the definition of work,then

$$dV = -\vec{E}.\vec{dr}$$

From this equation

$$E_{radial}=-\frac{dV}{dr}$$

Not it seems quite obvious that electric potential decreases in the direction of increasing electric field.